# Are 'using' blocks thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

If I am calling some data access methods from multiple threads, do I need to lock the code around the DB calls to ensure consistency, or are the using statements below atomic?

```
public static DataRow GetData(Int32 id)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);)         
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = ...
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(...)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(...)
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        return new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).FillWithRetry(dt, sqlGetEmail.CommandText);
    }
}
```

I don't think one thread can affect the connection object defined and 'in use' from another.

Comment: Do you want to open single connection at a time?

Comment: No, I don't mind multiple connections, as long as the data returned is consistent.

Comment: How that could be inconsistent as you are not updating it?

Comment: I am considering the threads switching between the cmd.Parameters.Add statements or between the add and the execute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using statements have *nothing* to do with thread-safety (or lack of).

They merely ensure that `Dispose` method of the used object is called when the block ends; but are otherwise equivalent to a manual `try..finally Dispose`.

In this particular case: since a *new* connection is opened on each thread then it is 'thread safe'. It still might not be atomic wrt. the database or other *shared* state.

Comment: @Rob That is outside of `using` :}

Comment: So, in short, the code above is not thread safe and needs a lock(_syncLock) statement around the entire body. Right?

Comment: @Ryan It is 'thread safe' insofar as that, with the SQL Server provider, the query will execute and return data in a thread-isolated manner. That is there will be no thread-related 'bug' with the implementation of carrying out the request. But it is still not an atomic operation (to the application itself or the database); it may be okay, or it may not - depend on what sort of guarantees are required.

Comment: Sorry atomic was a bad phrase, I should've used 'thread-safe' or 'consistent'. Without locking, there is no danger of one thread overwriting the value of (say) one of the params before the statement is then executed by the original thread?

Comment: @Ryan That is correct. There is no danger of 'overwriting the value of the params'. Most (I should hope all!) database providers are thread-safe if a *new* connection is used in each thread - and the resources resulting from (or relating to) the connection are used within said thread. Some may provide finer guarantees.

Comment: Ok, so my conclusion is that a lock(_syncLock) is required. Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan No... you do *not* need a lock at all.

Comment: @user2864740, sorry I didn't see your previous comment. Understood! No locking required!

Comment: Whether you need locking or not is not dependent on the using-statement. This is exactly the same question as asking whether you might get hit by a falling brick while eating an orange. Whether a brick might fall on your head is not dependent on you eating oranges so you cannot conclude that while eating oranges you will/won't need a helmet. The brick problem is due to other circumstances. If the objects involved register themselves with some global state, or are shared, using them in `using` statements might not be thread-safe but that is not because of the `using` statement.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't think one thread can affect the connection object defined and 'in use' from another.

So I suppose you are worrying your connection's concurrent access. The `using` statement is not a lock. If you want to use *exclusively* a connection or any other instance you should use:

```
lock(myConnection)
{
    // your code
}
```

What the `using` keyword is for that's described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

**However I think there is other misunderstandings here:**. In your example your connection is a local variable what is instantiated as many times as the control flow enters to your GetData method (even in different threads). So even the control flow reenters multiple times (and in different threads) to the method, no *shared* connection instance will be used, each entering to the method creates its own instance.

It *would be* different the case if the connection instance would be a *parameter*. Then you *should worry* about concurrency, and use a lock.

Conclusion: In your sample you do NOT need to worry about your connection instance concurrent access, and you do not need to use any locking semantics.

Interestingly in your sample using of `using` is indeed correct, because Connection is IDisposable, so you should apply a deterministic dispose guard around its usage with try/finally or better with its shortcut: the `using` keyword.